# Split string column into 2 columns, one numeric, and the other a date

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame called "prices" obtained by web scraping. The goal is to track the daily prices of the stocks on the Zimbabwe stock exchange.

Web scraping from the site:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
# Data from African Financials
url <- "https://africanfinancials.com/zimbabwe-stock-exchange-share-prices/"
prices <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = T)
prices <- prices[[1]]
```

The prices dataframe:

```
> prices

                   Counter   PriceRTGS cents  Volume ChangeRTGS cents ChangePercent YTDPercent
1            AFDS.zw Afdis   169.75 4 Apr 19       0             0.00         0.00%     10.95%
2          ARIS.zw Ariston     2.90 4 Apr 19     572            -0.03        -1.02%     20.83%
3     ARTD.zw ART Holdings     9.20 4 Apr 19       0             0.00         0.00%      4.55%
```

I'd like to split the "PriceRTGS cents" column into two columns "Price RTGS Cents" and "Date".

I tried using the below code but it captures the day of the month, 4, in the price column.

```
str_split_fixed(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`," ", 2)
colsplit(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`," ",c("Price RTGS Cents", "Date"))
```

I would like for the output to look like this:

```
                   Counter   Price RTGS Cents              Date         Volume ChangeRTGS cents ChangePercent YTDPercent
1            AFDS.zw Afdis             169.75         4/04/2019              0             0.00         0.00%     10.95%
2          ARIS.zw Ariston               2.90         4/04/2019            572            -0.03        -1.02%     20.83%
3     ARTD.zw ART Holdings               9.20         4/04/2019              0             0.00         0.00%      4.55%
```

dput data:

```
structure(list(Counter = c("AFDS.zw Afdis", "ARIS.zw Ariston", 
"ARTD.zw ART Holdings", "ASUN.zw Africansun", "AXIA.zw Axia", 
"BAT.zw BAT"), `PriceRTGS cents` = c("169.75 4 Apr 19", "2.90 4 Apr 19", 
"9.20 4 Apr 19", "15.00 4 Apr 19", "35.05 4 Apr 19", "3,000.00 4 Apr 19"
), Volume = c("0", "572", "0", "0", "8,557", "0"), `ChangeRTGS cents` = c(0, 
-0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0), ChangePercent = c("0.00%", "-1.02%", "0.00%", 
"0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%"), YTDPercent = c("10.95%", "20.83%", 
"4.55%", "50.00%", "-22.11%", "-9.09%")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share data with `dput(head(prices))`?!

Comment: try prices$date <- gsub("^.* ", "", prices$`PriceRTGS cents`) and prices$`PriceRTGS cents` <- gsub(" .*$", "", prices$`PriceRTGS cents`)

Comment: I’ve updated the question to include the dput data.

Comment: Your `str_split_fixed` solution works for me. In the rest of your data, is there not a consistent space after the price and before the date (and that is the first space in the string)?

Comment: @Andrew the price column includes the day, 4, from the Date column

Comment: @gm007 thanks for posting the web-scraping code. Figured out why your `str_split_fixed` solution wasn't working (see below). Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: similar to your `str_split_fixed` solution. It also removes the commas from your price variable so it can be coerced into `numeric` and formats the date column.

```
split_string <- str_split(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`, regex("\\s"), 2, simplify = T)

prices$Price <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", split_string[,1], fixed = T))
prices$Date <- as.Date(split_string[,2], format = "%d %b %y")

head(prices[-2])
               Counter Volume ChangeRTGS cents ChangePercent YTDPercent   Price       Date
1        AFDS.zw Afdis      0             0.00         0.00%     10.95%  169.75 2019-04-04
2      ARIS.zw Ariston    572            -0.03        -1.02%     20.83%    2.90 2019-04-04
3 ARTD.zw ART Holdings      0             0.00         0.00%      4.55%    9.20 2019-04-04
4   ASUN.zw Africansun      0             0.00         0.00%     50.00%   15.00 2019-04-04
5         AXIA.zw Axia  8,557             0.00         0.00%    -22.11%   35.05 2019-04-04
6           BAT.zw BAT      0             0.00         0.00%     -9.09% 3000.00 2019-04-04
```

The issue with the fixed solution is that it was not recognizing the space after the price, i.e.:

```
table(str_count(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`, fixed(" ")))

 2 
55
```

But it did using regex for whitespace, i.e.:

```
table(str_count(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`, regex("\\s")))

 3 
55
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just copy and paste your first prices datas into text editor and change the spaces with ";" (I had not seen your data edition yet).

```
prices <- read.table("dat.txt", sep=";", header=T)
```

Kind of "quick and dirty" code, but it's working:

```
str_split_fixed(prices$PriceRTGS.cents," ", 2)
new_prices <- data.frame(prices$Counter, str_split_fixed(prices$PriceRTGS.cents," ", 2), prices$Volume, prices$ChangeRTGS.cents, prices$ChangePercent, prices$YTDPercent)
colnames(new_prices) <- c("Counter", "PriceRTGS_cents", "Date",  "Volume", "ChangeRTGS cents", "ChangePercent",  "YTDPercent")
new_prices$Date <- gsub("Apr", "04", new_prices$Date)
new_prices$Date <- gsub(" ", "/", new_prices$Date)
new_prices <- data.frame(prices$Counter, new_prices$PriceRTGS_cents, new_prices$Date, prices$Volume, prices$ChangeRTGS.cents, prices$ChangePercent, prices$YTDPercent)
colnames(new_prices) <- c("Counter", "PriceRTGS_cents", "Date",  "Volume", "ChangeRTGS cents", "ChangePercent",  "YTDPercent")
new_prices
```

If you have other months than 'Apr', juste add others lines
(eg: if "Nov")

```
new_prices$Date <- gsub("Nov", "10", new_prices$Date)
new_prices$Date <- gsub(" ", "/", new_prices$Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative. Separator(-) and date formats,column names can be changed:

```
prices$Prices<-stringr::str_extract_all(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`,"\\d{1,}.*\\.\\d{1,}",simplify=T)

prices$Dates<-stringr::str_remove_all(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`,"\\d{1,}.*\\.\\d{1,} ")
prices %>% 
  select(-`PriceRTGS cents`) %>% 
  mutate(Dates=lubridate::dmy(Dates))
```

Result:

```
               Counter Volume ChangeRTGS cents ChangePercent YTDPercent   Prices      Dates
1        AFDS.zw Afdis      0             0.00         0.00%     10.95%   169.75 2019-04-04
2      ARIS.zw Ariston    572            -0.03        -1.02%     20.83%     2.90 2019-04-04
3 ARTD.zw ART Holdings      0             0.00         0.00%      4.55%     9.20 2019-04-04
4   ASUN.zw Africansun      0             0.00         0.00%     50.00%    15.00 2019-04-04
5         AXIA.zw Axia  8,557             0.00         0.00%    -22.11%    35.05 2019-04-04
6           BAT.zw BAT      0             0.00         0.00%     -9.09% 3,000.00 2019-04-04
```

Comment: Could I be missing a package? The Dates column is <NA> for me.

Comment: Load `tidyverse` or `stringr`,`lubridate`,`dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[,Date:=sub("^\\S+\\s+", "\\1", `PriceRTGS cents`)]
dt[,cents:=sub("^\\s*(\\S+\\S+).*", "\\1", `PriceRTGS cents`)]
```

**Note**- Remove original column later from `dt`

```
> dt <- subset(dt,select = -c(`PriceRTGS cents`))
> dt
                Counter Volume ChangeRTGS cents ChangePercent YTDPercent    cents     Date
1:        AFDS.zw Afdis      0             0.00         0.00%     10.95%   169.75 4 Apr 19
2:      ARIS.zw Ariston    572            -0.03        -1.02%     20.83%     2.90 4 Apr 19
3: ARTD.zw ART Holdings      0             0.00         0.00%      4.55%     9.20 4 Apr 19
4:   ASUN.zw Africansun      0             0.00         0.00%     50.00%    15.00 4 Apr 19
5:         AXIA.zw Axia  8,557             0.00         0.00%    -22.11%    35.05 4 Apr 19
6:           BAT.zw BAT      0             0.00         0.00%     -9.09% 3,000.00 4 Apr 19
```

**EDIT**- If you want `Date` as you mentioned then do this-

```
dt[,Date:=format(as.Date(sub("^\\S+\\s+", "\\1", `PriceRTGS cents`),format='%d %b %Y'),"%d/%m/%Y")]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is to split on empty space and create two parts of the string , first the price part and the remaining part together as date.

```
t(sapply(strsplit(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`,"\\s+"), function(x) 
  c(x[1], format(as.Date(paste0(x[-1], collapse = "-"), "%d-%b-%y"), "%d/%m/%Y"))))

#         [,1]           [,2]        
#[1,] "169.75"   "04/04/2019"
#[2,] "2.90"     "04/04/2019"
#[3,] "9.20"     "04/04/2019"
#[4,] "15.00"    "04/04/2019"
#[5,] "35.05"    "04/04/2019"
#[6,] "3,000.00" "04/04/2019"
```

You can then `cbind` these two columns to the original dataframe.

If you are ok to keep date columns as it is without any formatting, we can let go off and `as.Date` and `format` and shorten the code.

```
t(sapply(strsplit(prices$`PriceRTGS cents`,"\\s+"), function(x) 
             c(x[1], paste0(x[-1], collapse = "-"))))
```

Comment: I'm having issues replicating this. column [,2] has NA for me. I'm going to include the webscrape code in my original question.

Comment: @gm007 split it on whitespace instead. Updated the answer and it should work on your original data.